# junit wiki FibonacciTest code using junit4 fails to compile in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, fibonacci

I was trying to run the sample code from [junit wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) which uses a Parameterized test class.I found that the code  below causes a compilation error.

> > Fibonacci cannot be resolved to a variable
> >
> > Multiple markers at this
> >     line
> >         - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to    Object
> >         - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to    Object
> >         - Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to    Object

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
             Fibonacci,
             { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },{ 6, 8 } } });
}
```

I have the Fibonacci.java in the same package as this Test class,so it is not a path problem

However,when I modified this as below ,it compiled and ran the tests successfully

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
             { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 },{ 6, 8 }  });
}
```

I am using Eclipse juno (on ubuntu lucid) and it uses `/home/me/eclipsejuno/plugins/org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900/junit.jar` ..

Is this a bug with eclipse or is there an error with the code on the wiki ?

Comment: What compilation error?

Comment: Looks like an error on the wiki to me. A class name like `Fibonacci` isn't legal there. Why don't you fix the wiki?

Comment: @AlanStokes, updated my question.. seems like a problem in the wiki